# Android Native ads in Fragment too much requests

Tags: android, fragment, native-ads

I already created AdMob Native ads in Fragment and it works but after swiping app always request new ads and I think I'm creating too many requests.

So my question is am I really creating too many requests. If answer is yes then how could I do workaround. Please with some code I was searching for hours on google and didn't found any answers. If answer is no then it's all ok :)

My code:

public class ExerciseGuideActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ExerciseGuidePagerAdapter mAdapter;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private ViewPager mPager;
private View tag;
NativeExpressAdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_guide);

    mAdapter = new ExerciseGuidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
}

public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final java.lang.String ARG_PAGE = "arg_page";

    public MyFragment() {

    }

    public static MyFragment newInstance(int pageNumber) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        myFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        int pageNumber = arguments.getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        arguments.getInt(ARG_PAGE);

        final View v;

        if(pageNumber == 0) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_1, null);
        }else if(pageNumber == 1){
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_2, null);
        }else{
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_3, null);
        }

        NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl_ads);
                rl.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

}

Pager Adapter

```
public class ExerciseGuidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private Context context;
private String [] tabs = new String [] { "warm_up", "exercise", "cool_down" };

public ExerciseGuidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
    super(fm);
    context = c;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    ExerciseGuideActivity.MyFragment myFragment = ExerciseGuideActivity.MyFragment.newInstance(position);
    return myFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    int get_resource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(tabs[position], "string", context.getPackageName());
    return context.getString(get_resource);
}
```

}